# getContentLength and Accept-Ranges does not work twice

Tags: java, url, urlconnection

OK, so I have written some code to get the content length and accept range of a file from an url. The code is:

```
URLConnection conn2 = url.openConnection();
conn2.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", ua);
conn2.connect();
int k = conn2.getContentLength();
String ar = conn2.getHeaderField("Accept-Ranges");
InputStream inStream = conn2.getInputStream();
inStream.close();
```

The problem is pretty peculiar I think. The first time around, it works. The correct content length and accept range is given. However, when I alunch the applet the second time, the content length becomes incorrect by a long way, and the accept range becomes null. This problem happens to most files I have tried to access, always working the first time, and then failing the second time. The url, by the way is: http://static.clipcanvas.com/sample/clipcanvas_14348_DVCPRO_25.mov

Does anyone have any thoughts? I think maybe I am forgetting to close something, or something from the previous execution of the code may have 'cached' and then 'screwed up' the results from executing the second time.

By the way, ua is not the problem. I have used no ua, and then a default ua from my browser, the same problem still occurs.